# OMF(Object Module Format) length field appears incorrect

Tags: omf

I am a little confused, with the PUBDEF record in the OMF object format.
My assembler has generated a result which states the record is 4000 bytes, when it clearly is not so why would it do this?

[Image of Hex view of OMF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3oAh.png)

The 0xa0 and 0x0f is the record length in little endian format,

please view the specificaiton: http://pierrelib.pagesperso-orange.fr/exec_formats/OMF_v1.1.pdf

It also appears to state that the strings are zero bytes in length and at one point even has just a zero string length with no string provided. Maybe I am reading the file wrong? I have spent hours now and am struggling.

If anyone can help me with my issue as I am writing a linker and cannot continue without understanding this.

Thanks

Comment: I  have figured out that the 0x0f is the offset until the end of the string, but this makes no sense as the spec clearly shows both 0x0a and 0x0f as a little endian short that represents the size of the record.

Comment: You asked me in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41418521/968261) to take a look here. Taking. I'm not very familiar with OMF. However, given the context in which it's being asked (for a custom compiler), I may offer to look at ELF instead. In my [Smaller C compiler](https://github.com/alexfru/SmallerC) I assemble both 32-bit and 16-bit into ELF object files. From them I can generate executables for DOS (tiny model .COM, small and huge models .EXEs, DPMI and unreal mode EXEs), Windows (PE), Linux (ELF) and flat binaries. I do have a custom linker for this, though.

Comment: Ad LNAMES you are not wrong, the first string indeed has intentionally zero size. Segments with empty classname refer to it, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no PUBDEF record in the file. You seem to have miscalculated the previous record size:

```
0000:80 THEADR
000e:88 CoMENT
0032:96 LNAMES
0041:98 SEGDEF
004B:98 SEGDEF
0055:88 COMENT
005C:a0 LEDATA
006E:a0 LEDATA
007b:8a MODEND
```

Learn to use more sofisticated tools for OMF inspection, such as Tdump.exe or ODU.exe.

Comment: Do you have any links, the example executables you provided don't appear to run on Windows 10. I assume its for Win 98 and below. Could you provide me with some links please :)

Comment: @NibbleBits I'm using Object File Dumper, Public Domain by Sven B. Schreiber, similar product is available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/jwasm.hx-dos.p/files/DumpOmf16.zip/download
Tdump is Borland commercial sw, shipped with Turbo products, perhaps available as abandonware, described at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/TDUMP.EXE,_the_File_Dumping_Utility

Comment: Btw, most DOS stuff (not just games) works under DOSBox quite well. That's one of the ways I'm testing my compiler.